# AngularJS hide progress bar after ng-animate complete

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-animate

My requirement is to display a spinner image on every $route change request and hide the spinner image on success or error. I am using angular-animate.js  to slide the view after the $route success

```
<div ng-cloak ng-controller="sliderController">
<div ng-view ng-class="{slide: true, left: isDownwards, right: !isDownwards}">
</div>
</div>
```

I need to hide to progress image (Spinner) after the new page is loaded (ie : on complete page animation)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, I don't see anything that is showing what you're doing for the spinner. So this will be just a stab in the dark at what you're looking to accomplish.

One option is to use an app-wide progress bar. Think of how YouTube does page transitions. The [Angular Loading Bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/#) is a good solution to accomplish this. I think it uses `$http interceptors` to do it [(good explanation of interceptors)](http://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/).

---

Another option would be to use `$routeChangeStart` and `$routeChangeSuccess` that are part of the [`$route`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route) provider. You can simply have a `$scope` variable that triggers whether or not the image should be visible.

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next,current) {
    $scope.spinnerDisplayed = true;
});

$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, next,current) {
    $scope.spinnerDisplayed = false;
});
```

And then your HTML would just have a basic `ng-show/hide`

```
<div ng-show="spinnerDisplayed">
   <!-- some spinner image here -->
</div>
```